# Phalcon: Cannot use alias column in where/having clause

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, phalcon, calculated-columns

I have to select some location points with a distance from given coordinates. 
Presented query

```
$locations = Locations::query()->columns(['id','distance' => '(1+2)'])
                ->order('distance')
                ->having('distance < 10')
                ->execute();
```

produces error:

```
SELECT id, (1+2) AS distance FROM [Multiple\Base\Models\Locations] GROUP BY [distance < 10] ORDER BY distance (116)...
```

Why can I use 'distance' alias with order clause, but cannot with having/where?

How to get it?

The query below works, but i need to order resultset by distance and use distance in views...

```
$locations = Locations::query()->columns(['id'])
                    ->having('(1+2) < 10')
                    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation imposed by MySQL not Phalcon.  Try executing:

```
SELECT id, (1+2) AS distance FROM locations WHERE distance < 10;
```

from the mysql command line and you will receive the same error.